# dashed lines with google Chart API in a GWT project

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I am trying to make one of my lines in my  Line Chart a dotted line. Here is my java code

```
DataTable data = DataTable.create();
data.addColumn( ColumnType.NUMBER, "GaussianProcesses" );
data.addColumn( ColumnType.NUMBER, "SMOreg" );
data.addColumn( ColumnType.NUMBER, "LinearRegression" );
data.addColumn( ColumnType.NUMBER, "MultilayerPerceptron");
```

I would like to make the first two columns dashed/dotted line instead of a solid line.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the "certainty" role [as described here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but it is in JavaScript. Is there anyway that I can do it in java using the GWT?

Comment: @user1527872 you have to extend the DataTable class and implement the JavaScript functions using ``JSNI``. Just have a look at the DataTable source code how they ``addColumn()`` is implemented.